# Vertical centering problem

Tags: vertical-alignment

How to vertically center the label **(A)** in the picture below. I use the following code:

```
\begin{enumerate}[nosep,label=(\Alph*),font=\bfseries]
\item \textbf{Does the finite exchange property always imply the full exchange 
  property?}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just place it in a `\parbox[c]`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[nosep,label=(\Alph*),font=\bfseries]
\item \parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\textbf{Does the finite exchange property always imply the full exchange 
  property?}}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

EDIT:
Select your space before using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\def\myspace{1cm}
\begin{enumerate}[nosep,label=(\Alph*),font=\bfseries]
\item \hspace{\myspace}\parbox[c]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\myspace}{\textbf{Does the finite exchange property always imply the full exchange 
  property?}}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. One more question (if possible): Is it possible to leave some little space between the label **(A)** and the statement?!.

Comment: Edited @HusseinEid ... Happy TeXing!

Comment: Great. Thanks alot.